# Написать 2 sql запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

1.Какова доля заказов со скидкой?
2.Какая самая популярная скидка (название) и какая сумма общих затрат по ней? Самая популярная скидка – это скидка, по которой получились наибольшие затраты в деньгах.

Даны две таблицы в Базе данных:

1.orders (id, disc_id)
2.discounts (id, name, count)

name – название скидки
count – скидка в рублях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какова доля заказов со скидкой?

```
SELECT COUNT(disc_id)/COUNT(*) * 100 AS PercentageWithDiscont FROM orders
```

Какая самая популярная скидка (название) и какая сумма общих затрат по ней?

Если взять за основу

```
SELECT 
     orders.disc_id, 
     discounts.name, 
     Count(*) AS Popularity, 
     Count(*) * discounts.count TotalDiscounts 
FROM orders 
  LEFT JOIN discounts 
  ON discounts.id = orders.disc_id 
GROUP BY 
  orders.disc_id, 
  discounts.name
```

обернуть это в табличное выражение, отсортировать по TotalDiscounts, Popularity так как вам нужно то получите в топе то что нужно. добавите `SELECT TOP 1` и все

Comment: с первым запросом думаю все отлично, спасибо. Однако здесь проблема во втором и в том, что мы не можем проверить это на практике, потому что таблицы в наличии у нас есть (это же как билет в университете), однако показав одному из преподавателей, он сказал, что второй запрос не верен и его нужно перепроверить, одно из наставлений - чистый sql не сортирует по результатам функций.